# AngularJS: writing a capatilize directive does not seem to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS so if i'm completely off track i apologize.

Template (which is iterated):

```
<div class="title">
            <input ng-model="menuItem.kind" capitalize-first />
</div>
```

Directive (to capitalize):

```
angular.module('phonecat', []).directive('capitalizeFirst', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
            var capitalized = inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                inputValue.substring(1);
            if(capitalized !== inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }

            return capitalized;
        }
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
        capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]);  // capitalize initial value
    }
};
});
```

The result is  a blank span. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to implement? Converting what user typed to capitalized chars in the text box while typing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `scope[attrs.ngModel]`. AngularJs will not set `scope['menuItem.kind'] = ...`, but `scope.menuItem.kind = ...`.

Additionally, the value might had been resolved to a parent scope. So your best choice is to use `ngModel.$modelValue` to get the current model value of `ngModel` (`capitalize(modelCtrl.$modelValue);`).

This leads to another problem. You don't have this value in linking phase, it's lightly async. To workaround it, all you need is to inject `$timeout` and run this code asynchronously:

```js
$timeout(function() {
  capitalize(modelCtrl.$modelValue);
}, 0);
```

So, summarizing, all you need is to change your directive last line to the one above, and this will solve the problem. All the rest is ok, take a look at [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140?p=preview).